# Continuously execute runnables on the UI thread

Tags: java, android

I need to run a sequence of runnables on the main (ui) thread with a given delay between them indefinitely until signalled to stop. Code:

```
public class UiLoop {

    private Handler h;
    private AtomicBoolean breakLoop;

    @UiThread
    public UiLoop() {

        if (Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not called on ui thread!");
        }

        h = new Handler();
        breakLoop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }

    /**
     * Break out of the loop on the next iteration.
     */
    public void breakLoop() {
        this.breakLoop.set(true);
    }


    /**
     * @param workers    A Deque of runnables to execute sequentially.
     * @param delay The delay between executing the runnables. This is excluding the time it
     *              takes for the runnable to complete.
     */
    @UiThread
    public void loop(Deque<Runnable> workers, int delay) {

        if (Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not called on ui thread!");
        }

        if (workers.isEmpty()) return;

        if (breakLoop.get()) return;

        final Runnable first = workers.removeFirst();
        h.post(first);
        workers.addLast(first);
        h.postDelayed(() -> loop(workers, delay), delay);

    }
}
```

Is the above code OK?

PS: I am using retrolambda to convert Anonymous Inner Classes to lambda functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your variable names could be more clear.  `h` is a poor choice, for example.  `loop` is probably not a great name for a method either - maybe `startLoop`?
2. You have inconsistent code style.  Some one-line `if` blocks are in curlies while others are not.
3. Why `final Runnable first`?  It's fine if you want to use `final` wherever possible, but that doesn't appear to be the case with the rest of the code, and there's no explicit reason for it be `final`, so what is the strategy here?
4. I'd save the `Runnable` you pass to `postDelayed` as an instance member instead of creating a new one each time.
5. Why do you use an explicit `this` in `this.breakLoop.set`, but nowhere else?  I'd choose one or the other.
6. If you've got those tests to ensure everything is happening on the main thread, then why `h.post(first)`?  Wouldn't `first.run()` to the same thing?

Comment: Thanks! Regarding 4. I am just popping it from the queue, not creating it.

Comment: in `h.postDelayed(() -> loop(workers, delay), delay);`, that lambda expression is creating a new `Runnable` instance